# Overriding a function in python

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, superclass

I have the following base class (code shortened):

```
class SignupForm(GroupForm):

    username = forms.CharField(
        label = _("Username"),
        max_length = 30,
        widget = forms.TextInput()
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if REQUIRED_EMAIL or EMAIL_VERIFICATION or EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION:
            self.fields["email"].label = ugettext("Email")
            self.fields["email"].required = True
        else:
            self.fields["email"].label = ugettext("Email (optional)")
            self.fields["email"].required = False


    def after_signup(self, user, **kwargs):
        """
        An extension point for subclasses.
        """
        pass
```

What I wanna do is override the `after_signup()` function and the `username` field like so:

```
class CompanySignupForm(SignupForm):
    #TODO: override fields for company signup form

    username = forms.CharField(
        label = _("Username TEST"),
        max_length = 30,
        widget = forms.TextInput()
    )

    def after_signup(self, user, **kwargs):
        """
        An extension point for subclasses.
        """
        print str('after_signup is has been overwritten')
```

My Problem:
Only the username field shows the desired behavior. The `after_signup()` function get never called. Instead the `after_signup()` function of the base class `SignupForm` gets called. What am I doning wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
the imports: 
from django import forms 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _, ugettext
```

instantiating CompanySignupForm:

```
url(r"^signup/$", CompanySignupForm.as_view(), name="acct_signup")
```

after_signup() is beeing called from a function in the base class:

```
def save(self, request=None): 
    # more code here
    # ...
    self.after_signup(new_user)
```

Comment: Could you show us how you are instantiating `CompanySignupForm` and calling `after_signup()`?

Comment: the imports are fine i get no errors. but here they are: from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _, ugettext

Comment: instantiating CompanySignupForm:     url(r"^signup/$", CompanySignupForm.as_view(), name="acct_signup")

Comment: after_signup() is beeing called from a function in the base class: def save(self, request=None):
    
    self.after_signup(new_user)

Comment: @JoheGreen: You can [edit] your question and add there this information. Comments with code are hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isinstance()` to check an instance’s type and `.__class__` to make sure you are  instantiating `CompanySignupForm`.

Also you might want to create an `__init__` method on the `CompanySignupForm` to ensure it's not just instantiating the super class.

Note: Reading your edit more closely your not calling after_signup directly the base class function save is right? This will then call it's local method after_signup if it exists. I'd take that function out of the base class and force it to call the inherited functions

To check the version run:

```
signup = CompanySignupForm.as_view()
print signup.__class__

url(r"^signup/$", signup, name="acct_signup")
```

Comment: Added code to check class can you include the GroupForm code, or the code that has as_view() and save() these are calling the GroupForm after_signup() function I think as they are base level functions.